Connecting API python-script with Figma file problem
I’m trying to create script, which will upload images from local pc storage to Figma file. I do it through token, but get error 403 “Invalid Token”. The token is taken from account - settings - security. It is correctly written, the token account and file account is one and mine. May be the issue with scopes, but how to check it… while generating token I extended all rights that I could. There’s simple checking code with similar error:
import requests

TOKEN = “personal token”
FILE_KEY = “the string between “design” and /name of file”
HEADERS = {“Authorization”: f"Bearer {TOKEN}"}

url = f"https://api.figma.com/v1/files/{FILE_KEY}"
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(“OK”)
elif response.status_code == 403:
    print(“Error 403: Invalid token.”)
elif response.status_code == 401:
    print(“Error 401”)
else:
    print(f"Error {response.status_code}: {response.text}")

Maybe someone can direct me?
